# How to add all the dates list from excel sheet and will ingest to SQL Server using Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I would like to know on how we ingest add all the dates in column from excel sheet to SQL Server using Logic Apps. I tried to use Compose and addDays expression but there's an error. Can you please help us what would be the right expression to show all the dates to the SQL tables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Looking forward to ingest all the dates in the SQL Tables.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `addDays` is used to add or remove a number of days from the given timestamp. I don't think that is what you are looking to do. Please refer [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#addDays) for Logic apps expressions.

Comment: Hello @Prinkpan, what would be the possible solution to add dates other than using addDays? since you've mentioned it is only used to add or remove a number of days from the given timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and expected results are as below:

**`My table in Excel (Input):`**

[image]

**`Design:`**

[image]

```
addDays('1899-12-30', int(items('For_each')?['Date']))
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: I added a new post to provide the screenshot of input and output. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What error you have got, where have you provided it

Comment: I added a new post again for the error. Thank you